# Comparing Radio Button List's SelectedIndex to SelectedIndex[0] or Selectedindex[1]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a radio button list control on my ascx page and have a bunch of options (5) to show while rendering. I pull these choices through a sharepoint list item. 
I would like to check to see the SelectedIndex is the 1st radiobutton, 2nd , 3rd, 4th or 5th. 
What is the right syntax to do this comparison?
rBtnList.SelectedIndex==?

I need to do this as I would like to increment a a counter that I have below each TotalChoice columns. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use switch...case..something like below

```
switch (rBtnList.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                    //something to do;
                break;
            case 1:
                //something to do
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Paabobo Thanks a bunch. Ill get back to you if I have any trouble. But do let me know if there is a way to compare using properties.